# MYSQL PHP query

Tags: php, mysql

I am tring to run this query(works in Heidi sql) but I cant get it to work on my site through php.

```
$ID_CARTERA= $_GET['id'];   

$result = mysql_query("

SELECT    K.Date_as_of,
      K.Fund_Name,
      K.Fund_Benchmark_name,
      K.Class_Name,
      K.Special_Class_Name,
      ROUND(sum(case K.Column_ID
              when 1 then K.Fund_Yield
              else 0
            end ), 2) 'Fund 1 Mes %',
      ROUND(sum(case K.Column_ID
              when 2 then K.Fund_Yield
              else 0
            end ), 2) 'Fund 6 Meses %',
      ROUND(sum(case K.Column_ID
              when 5 then K.Fund_Yield
              else 0
            end ), 2) 'Fund Año Corrido %',
      ROUND(sum(case K.Column_ID
              when 3 then K.Fund_Yield
              else 0
            end ), 2) 'Fund 1 Año %',
      ROUND(sum(case K.Column_ID
              when 4 then K.Fund_Yield
              else 0
            end ), 2) 'Fund 2 Años %',
      ROUND(sum(case K.Column_ID
              when 1 then K.Fund_Benchmark_Yield
              else 0
            end ),
                FROM      (select
          DATE_FORMAT(A.F_HASTACORTE, '%d/%m/%Y') 'Date_as_of',
          D.DES_CARTERA_CC Fund_Name,
          G.DES_CARTERA_CC Fund_Benchmark_name,
          B.DES_CARTERACLASE Class_Name,
          C.DES_CARTERACLASE_ESP Special_Class_Name,
          H.ID_COLUMNA Column_ID,
          H.DES_COLUMNA Column_labels,
          A.POR_RENTCARTERA Fund_Yield,
          A.POR_RENTBENCH Fund_Benchmark_Yield,
          I.POR_RENTCLASE Class_Yield,
          J.POR_RENTCLASEESP Special_Class_Yield,
          A.POR_RENTMENOSBENCH Plus_Minus_Fund_Benchmark,
          A.POR_RENTMENOSCLASE Plus_Minus_Class,
          A.POR_RENTMENOSCLASEESP Plus_Minus_Special_Class,
          A.POR_PERCENTILCLASE Percentile_Class,
          A.POR_PERCENTILCLASEESP Percentile_Special_Class
FROM      dr_rentmovil_carteras A
      JOIN mcarteras                D ON ( A.ID_CARTERA          = D.ID_CARTERA )
      JOIN mcarteras_clases         B ON ( D.ID_CARTERACLASE     = B.ID_CARTERACLASE )
      JOIN mcarteras_clasesesp      C ON ( D.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = C.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP )

      JOIN mpaises                  E ON ( A.F_HASTACORTE        = E.F_ULT_CIERRE_DIARIO)
      JOIN det_refcru_carterasbench F ON ( A.ID_CARTERA          = F.ID_CARTERA )
      JOIN mcarteras                G ON ( F.ID_CARTERABENCH     = G.ID_CARTERA )
      JOIN dformatos                H ON ( A.ID_COLUMNA          = H.ID_COLUMNA )
      JOIN dr_rentmovil_clases      I ON ( A.ID_COLUMNA          = I.ID_COLUMNA AND E.F_ULT_CIERRE_DIARIO = I.F_HASTACORTE and B.ID_CARTERACLASE = I.ID_CARTERACLASE )
      JOIN dr_rentmovil_clasesesp   J ON ( A.ID_COLUMNA          = J.ID_COLUMNA AND E.F_ULT_CIERRE_DIARIO = J.F_HASTACORTE and C.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = J.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP )
WHERE     A.ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA ) K


")
or die(mysql_error());
```

This is the error I get:
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (select DATE_FORMAT(F_ULT_CIERRE_MENSUAL, '%d/%m/%Y') 'Datos' at line 30`

I have been unable to narrow the problem.

Comment: There's a comma on the line preceding the FROM. You need to delete it.

Comment: remove then comma before the FROM keyword

Comment: as an aside, don't use mysql_* functions; they are deprecated use mysqli or PDO objects

Comment: Maybe it's just me .. but I don't see that line in the query...